# Fantasy book about a male werewolf and oracle

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

The story I am looking for is a werewolf erotica.

The story has a werewolf male and an oracle. The oracle was born a werewolf (but doesn't know it until later after a certain chunk of the novel) without shifting ability. She is the female mate of the werewolf male and is saved from a vampire who dies in the process (isn't the same vampire as the dead wife one). Both have to work together to stop an evil god from becoming invincible. The evil god tries to kill the god of light but a gargoyle whom has a magic disruption magic stops her because her invincible status is only half perfect (forced by an ancient magic because of what happened when the Oracle's thwarts her killing her mate).

The story is, I think, the 2nd to last in a series of books). The book has an important point in which the oracle causes indirect harm to stop her mate from harm after seeing him almost insane from said god at half or 3/4 of story read, directly starting the future she sees, but lives and gets him back from insanity to kill the god of darkness in the end of the novel or novella at least to the pair's knowledge.

Also the person presumably dead is in the last novel pretending to be a vampire's dead or brought-back wife who in reality is just a pretender. Also I know the oracle mates with the werewolf at New Las Vegas, Nevada.
This is in 1/4 to the 1st part of the storyline.

Comment: Some of this is incomprehensible. I tried to polish this but some of it I just don't understand. I encourage you to take some time to properly edit your question.

Comment: [Merry Ravenell's Oracle series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/208500-the-oracle)? It partially matches. The oracle is *Gianna* and in book 2 *Iron Oracle* she allows the bond to her mate *Gabel* to be broken (which drives him insane) to defeat the dark wolf *Magnes*. However *Magnes* isn't a god, and *Gianna* can shift. The *god of light* would be the *Moon Goddess*, who is the goddess of all werewolves. If this is the book I can post a detailed answer.

Comment: I edited the post